# No module found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, caffe, pycaffe

I install caffe and it worked fine. In cmd, I can import it use python, but when I use jupyter notebook, I can't import it.

[image]

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: try `pip install caffe`

Comment: It is not ok. When I try to use 'pip install caffe'. It displayed like this:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement caffe (from versions: )                                                  
No matching distribution found for caffe

Comment: Which python version you are using ? In command line it is showing 2.7, maybe in Jupyter you have other version.

Comment: I use jupyter in my university serve, and only have  python 2.7

Comment: Better use `virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have put `/home/mltitan/Workspace/caffepython` in the path instead of `/home/mltitan/Workspace/caffe/python` which may have been your intention.

Adding the strings together as you have done will not insert the slash in the path. Best practise is to use `os.path.join` to handle this:

```
import os
import sys

caffe_root = '/home/mltitan/Workspace/caffe'
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(caffe_root, 'python'))
import caffe
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. It it ok now